# Angular 4 Nested *ngFor not working

Tags: angular

i am getting data from rest API, 1 Level data is repeating good but Children are not working. Somebody help me please.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list">
<div class="isolate">       
    <div class="info-box">
        <span class="info-box-text">{{item.Name}}</span>
        <div>{{item.Stores.length}}</div>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="item.HasChildren"> 
        <div *ngFor="let child of list">
            <div class="info-box">
                 <span class="info-box-text">{{child.Children.Name}}</span>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Should that be `let child of item`?

Comment: While asking the question try to explain your code as well you you have tried and achieved from it and what you are missing.

Comment: Add your json data in the question

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser console?

Comment: here is no error in console

Comment: My TypeScript Code

`ngOnInit() {
 this.apiService.CommunitiesGetAllTree().subscribe(result => {
  this.list = result;
 });
}`

Comment: This doesn't help because it doesn't provide what the returned data looks like.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want

```
 <div *ngFor="let child of item">
```

instead of

```
 <div *ngFor="let child of list">
```

Comment: `<div *ngFor="let child of list">` if i am doing this its showing 2 empty div but in my json hav 3 children's

Comment: Your question doesn't contain any information about what the data looks like. Can you please add the code that builds a `list` with sample data that allows to reproduce?